# Amavis is not installed - CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

Getting this error when installing Modoboa via this link https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/email-server-centos-7-modoboa

```
Installing amavis
Package amavisd-new is obsoleted by amavis, trying to install amavis-2.12.0-10.el7.noarch instead
Package lz4-1.7.5-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/maria
db.service.
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mariadb.service
Amavis is not installed
```

It would be very helpful if some can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things

1. go to folder where you cloned modoboa git repo and run:

```
sed -i 's/amavisd-new/amavis/g' ./modoboa-installer/modoboa_installer/scripts/amavis.py
```

Script was searching for package amavisd-new but package naming was changed for amavis in Centos

2. Modoboa installer don't have yet files for amavis ver 2.12 but you can copy older sql template

```
cp modoboa-installer/modoboa_installer/scripts/files/amavis/amavis_mysql_2.11.X.sql modoboa-installer/modoboa_installer/scripts/files/amavis/amavis_mysql_2.12.X.sql
```

if you want to use postgresql do the same for postgres sql file.

and after that re-run installer should work fine :)